# Keep state in react inside context after logged in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I'm coding a web react app with sign in. In my server side I'm using express, jwt and sending a httpOnly cookie with the token when succesfully log in. When user logs in, I'm trying to keep state in the client (e.x, loggedIn = true) inside of a context, but every time that context is rendered it comes back to default state (undefined). How could i keep that state in memory?

My user route, that works as expected (backend):

```
users.post('/login',async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {userName,userPass} = req.body
    const u = await models.User.findOne({
      userid: userName
    })
    if (!u) res.status(404).end()

    if (bcrypt.compare(userPass,u.password)) {
      // JWT TOKEN
      const t = c_auth(u._id)
      res.status(200).cookie("session",t,{
        httpOnly:true
      }).end()
    } else {
      res.status(404).end()
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log({'ERROR':e})
    res.status(500).end()
  }
})
```

My user provider that returns true when request is ok (client):

```
get: async (user,pass) => {
    try {
      const req = await axios.post('/users/login',{
        userName: user,
        userPass: pass
      })
      if (req.status === 200) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log({'ERROR':e})
      return false
    }
  }
```

Login submit function (client):

```
import {useAuth} from '../../../../contexts/AuthContext.js'
const {setLoggedIn} = useAuth()
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
     if (await users.get(data.userName,data.userPass)) {
        setLoggedIn(true)
        // ^---> Trying to set loggedIn state to true in context

        window.location.replace('/')
     } else {
          alert(`Incorrect.`)
     }
}
```

Auth context:

```
const AuthContext = createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}
export function AuthProvider ({children}) {

    const [loggedIn,setLoggedIn] = useState()

    console.log(loggedIn)
    // ^---> Getting true after login, 
    // undefined (default useState) after re-render


    const value = {
        loggedIn,
        setLoggedIn
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

App.js:

```
import {AuthProvider} from './contexts/AuthContext'
function App() {
  return (
  <AuthProvider>
    <div className="App">
        <Navigation/>
        <main>
          <Router>
            <Routes>
              ...Routes
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        </main>
    </div>
  </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

I suppose that react memo could be the solution, but I don't understand quite well how it works. Also, is it correct not to use the `setLoggedIn` in the AuthContext itself? I tried to call the login or sign up function (second piece of code) from the AuthContext, but can't set state since its unmounted. Would need to do that inside a useEffect and that's not what I'm looking for since I wouldn`t be able to export that function. All help is appreciated.

## EDIT: fixed

The problem solved after changing `window.location.replace` to the `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`, causing a refresh:

```
import {useAuth} from '../../../../contexts/AuthContext.js'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
const {setLoggedIn} = useAuth()
const navigate = useNavigate()
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
     if (await users.get(data.userName,data.userPass)) {
        setLoggedIn(true)
        navigate('/')
     } else {
        alert(`Incorrect.`)
     }
}
```

Also in my navbar I was using `<a href>` tags instead of `<Link to>` from 'react-router-dom'. That fixes the problem when I go to a different page from the navbar, so it doesn't 'refresh'.

Comment: I think the problem here is you using `window.location.replace('/')`. It cause *refresh* not rerender. If you want to go back to '/' but still keep that context. you should use ReactRouter navigate function.

Comment: if it not work, please add a `codesandbox`

Comment: Ok, that works but just after login. I mean, if I go to other page after logged in,  `AuthContext` `loggedIn` state comes back to undefined again. Update: I tried wraping `authProvider` inside `React.memo()` (`export default React.memo(AuthProvider)`) but has the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you create some request-like function and upload a `codesandbox` ?

Comment: Problem is fixed, see edit. Thanks for replying!